# Oracle date time

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01830

I have four fields:

- Start_Date = 16-Jun-10
- Start_Time = 14:37
- End_Date = 16-Jun-10
- End_Time = 14:38

I need to calculate the difference from start to end.  I tried using the to_date(Start_date || Start_Time) but keep getting this error message:

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830.00000 - "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Thank you for your help.
David

Comment: I assume all four columns are VARCHARs?

Answer (score 5):

```
to_date(Start_date||start_time,'DD-MON-YYHH24:MI')
```